# Perl - how can I match strings that are not exactly the same?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a list of strings I want to find within a file. This would be fairly simple to accomplish if the strings in my list and in the file matched exactly. Unfortunately, there are typos and variations on the name. Here's an example of how some of these strings differ

```
List          File
B-Arrestin    Beta-Arrestin
Becn-1        BECN 1
CRM-E4        CRME4
```

Note that each of those pairs should count as a match despite being different strings.
I know that I could categorize every kind of variation and write separate REGEX to identify matches but that is cumbersome enough that I might be better off manually looking for matches. I think the best solution for my problem would be some kind of expression that says:

"Match this string exactly but still count it as a match if there are X characters that do not match"

Does something like this exist? Is there another way to match strings that are not exactly the same but close?

Comment: Stripping non-alphanumeric characters and doing a case-insensitive comparison will work for the second and third lines. Of course, if your file also had `B-Ecn-1` that would also be (incorrectly, I assume) flagged as a match. Can you make a list of prefixes and their abbreviations to cover the first case, e.g. Beta -> B ?

Comment: The problem with that kind of approach is that I don't know the full scope of these kinds of variations that exist. I am confident that I'll instantly spot a false match by eye, however, which is why I'm hoping there is a way to do not-quite-exact string matching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [200_success pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26745090), you can do fuzzy matching with [`Text::Fuzzy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Fuzzy), which computes the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between bits of text. You will have to play with what maximum Levenshtein distance you want to allow, but if you do a case-insensitive comparison, the maximum distance in your sample data is three:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Text::Fuzzy;

my $max_dist = 3;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($string1, $string2) = split ' ', $_, 2;

    my $tf = Text::Fuzzy->new(lc $string1);
    say "'$string1' matches '$string2'" if $tf->distance(lc $string2) <= $max_dist;
}

__DATA__
B-Arrestin    Beta-Arrestin
Becn-1        BECN 1
CRM-E4        CRME4
```

#### Output:

```
'B-Arrestin' matches 'Beta-Arrestin'
'Becn-1' matches 'BECN 1'
'CRM-E4' matches 'CRME4'
```

Answer (score 3):

There are CPAN modules for that:

- [`String::Approx`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::Approx)
- [`Text::Fuzzy`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Fuzzy)

Comment: As is normal, the answer is "CPAN has a module for that"

Comment: Based on the OP's sample data, `String::Approx` might not be the best tool. From the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Approx#DESCRIPTION): *"`String::Approx` is not well-suited for comparing strings of different length..."*